# Date Specific Field Level Security with Formula Validation

Tags: formula, opportunity, security

I want to create field level security on certain fields after the 10th of the following month for all ClosedDates within one month for everyone but finance people. For example, if a ClosedDate is in November, I want to restrict team access after December **10th**. This is a little more specified than most solutions I've seen (doing it by month). 
 
My pseudo code for month works similar to I'd want for the after the 10th thought: 
 
`if ClosedDate <= TODAY() – 30 restrict entry`

Am I able to get this specific using the `DATE` formula? 
Using [this](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/210/11/en-us/sfdc/pdf/formula_date_time_tipsheet.pdf) as a guide, I don't see it.

If this isn't possible, I don't want to create another record type, but would prefer to use an approvals process.

Comment: What kind of restrict access you want to perform? edit or read? If its edit, you could try to play around with a validation rule that prevents changes to anyone but Finance using the `ISCHANGED`

Comment: I want to restrict editing after the 10th of a following month. I think `ISCHANGED` could be tied to an approval process. I just don't know if saying the previous month plus 10 days of this one qualify this closed date as restricted from editing.